# Getting a field value from known document in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want a user to give a value in my app and other user to see it. But i can upload data to firebase but not get it on the other side. I have null safety enabled on flutter. The code is :-

```
child: StreamBuilder(
stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Collection name').doc('doc id').snapshots()
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.hasData){
                      return Text(snapshot.data['Field name'].toString());  // here my editor shows error saying 'The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.' and asks for a null check and then shows error again
                    }
                    return Text('Nothing');
                  }
                ),
```

Edit: I am getting only 'type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast' as the error

And if I change

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
                      return Text(snapshot.data['Field name'].toString());
```

to

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                      }
```

i get output as
'Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot''
where the data should be.
I am using null check dart

Comment: what is firebasedb equal to? Also share a screenshot of the database

Comment: the firebasedb is equal to the FirebaseFirestore.instacne.collection('collection').snapshot(); And sorry i cant get a screenshot due to some problem of maybe points. IDK what that is i am new to stack. there is just one doc in there. i have updated it please see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thannks for everyone's support, but i have accidently found and answer. I read that the data type of that is DocumentSnapshot and this worked for me

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    var numGuess = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot;
                    return Text(numGuess['Field name'].toString());
                  }
                  return Text('Nothing');
                }
```

```
This works for null safety.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving a collection then try the following:

```
return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[0].data()["Field Name"]);
```

A collection will return a list of documents, therefore use the `docs` property to be able to access the document. The above code will show the field in the first document in the list, it's better if you use a `listview` to return all documents.

Check:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. 
This is the error i am getting on trying this code. Do I need a special library for this. i m using cloud firestore and firebase core.

Comment: Can it be a library or update problem. How can i update everything?

Comment: If it matters,  there is a single collection in my firebase with a single document in it which has 2 vaiables in it

Comment: @AnirudhAgrawal do the following `child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>(`

Answer (score 0):

Give datatype to your StreamBuilder like this

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
            stream:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Collection name').doc('doc id').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data?.data()?['Field name']);
              }
              return Text('Nothing');
            },
          ),
```

Comment: This is the error i get while trying your code.
The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Can it be a library or update problem. How can i update everything?

Comment: Your project support null safety? Which cloud_firestore version are you using?

Comment: If it matters,  there is a single collection in my firebase with a single document in it which has 2 vaiables in it

Comment: how to find firestore version?

Comment: i dont know that but i have made my firestore about 1 week ago onle. so it must be the version which is latest.

Comment: according to google, it must be Firebase CLI v9.10.0

Comment: but i know it does support null safety striclty